# How to call a method of a class from another class?

Tags: python, oop, class

I want to call a method of a class from another class. I'd like to do something like this.

```
class A:
    def meth(self):
        B.meth1()

class B:
    def meth1(self):
        pass

a = A()
a.meth()
```

I get the following error :

```
TypeError: unbound method meth1() must be called with B instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

The example above is probably a bit vague. Here's what I exactly intend to do :

```
class A:
    def meth(self, data):
        if data[0] == '/':
            B.handleCOMMAND(data)

class B:
    def handleCOMMAND(self, data):
        """
        Some code to handle some command.
        """
```

**Update 2:**

```
class A:
    def meth(self, data):
        if data[0] == '/':
            B.handleCOMMAND(data)

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = 'CHAT'

    def handleCOMMAND(self, data):
        if data.strip().split()[1] == 'send':
             self.state == 'RECV-FILE'
```

The main problem I am facing is that :

'self.state' is an instance variable in class B. And depending on what 'data' meth() of class A gets, handleCOMMAND of class B needs to be invoked which is supposed to alter the value of 'self.state'

Comment: What do you want the effect of that to be?  In general a `B` method needs a `B` instance to work, but if you're calling from `A`, you don't have a `B` instance.  (If `B.meth1` doesn't need an instance, make it a classmethod instead.  If it doesn't even need the class, take it out of the class and make it a function.)

Comment: if you just want to be able to use one of class B methods for class A, you should use [inheritance](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) for this. Is this what you want?

Comment: Maybe you want `B.meth1` to be a `staticmethod`?  Without more details, it's really hard to know anything for sure.

Comment: @RyanSaxe: That _might_ be the answer, but it's certainly not guaranteed, and probably not even the most likely possibility. (As mgilson says, without knowing his design, it's impossible to be sure.)

Comment: This is very true, which is why I asked if that's what he wanted...But the way he asks it it seems as though he wants to be able to call methods from class B in class A, which is inheritance. What do you mean by most likely possibility? possibility of what he is asking?

Comment: @RyanSaxe: I mean what he's most likely to want, assuming his design isn't misguided. (Of course it's entirely possible that his design _is_ misguided—but, if so, it's better to get to the real question and answering that, than to help him write the wrong code.)

Comment: @RyanSaxe Apart from the handleCOMAND method, their really isnt anything in common between the two classes in my original code. So I dont really want it to inherit the other.

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta: So what do `A` and `B` actually represent? Maybe a client connection and a stateful command processor? If so, do you want a single `B` for each `A`, a single `B` shared by all `A`s, a single `B` shared by many but not necessarily all `A`s, or…? Once you can answer that, translating the answer into code is easy; until you can answer that, it's impossible.

Comment: absolutely nothing in common? Because from your new update what seems like a viable option is to make class `A` and `B` both inherit from a class `C` and that class can have a `handleCOMMAND` function. This way both `B` and `A` can use that function. Again, could just not be what you want...if it is, I'll post an answer for that code

Comment: @abarnert A is a class responsible asynchronously receiving user input and then forwarding it to the server. B  is ChatProtocol class that is responsible for making connections to the server and other network related tasks. (I'm using Twisted. Do you want me to post the original code?)

Comment: You don't need to post the original code—in fact, you shouldn't. Post a _stripped-down version_ of the code, just enough to demonstrate the relationships between the important objects. Or, if you can answer my questions, you don't need code.

Comment: @RyanSaxe: That's like arguing that the only possible relationship between a protocol and a transport, or between BeautifulSoup and its parser, etc. is inheritance.

Comment: I'm not saying it's the only possible one, I'm just saying that it is a method that works, but it is more useful in different situations. If he has a multitude of methods in `B` or `A` that he wants to use on the other, inheritance would be a good way to make this more efficient. I am in no way arguing that it is the only thing

Comment: @abarnert I made a 2nd update. I've defined the relationship there.

Comment: You _still_ haven't defined the relationship—all you've done is demonstrate even better why you need to do so. Since each `B` object clearly has important state (in a variable called `state`), the `A` instance has to pick _the right_ `B` instance. So… which one is that? How is the `A` supposed to know? Who creates the `A` and `B` instances at runtime, and calls methods on them? Does it create exactly one `B` for each `A`? Or one `B` shared by multiple `A`s, or vice versa, or both?

Comment: And to put it more concretely: Read my answer. Your design is probably like one of the 3 (well, 2-1/2) designs I showed how to code. If it is, which one is it? Then you know how to code it. If it isn't, describe in what way it isn't like those designs, and we can help you figure out what design it _is_ like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call an instance method unless you have an instance to call it on.

Without knowing what your design goals are, it's impossible to tell you where the instance should come from, but there are two particularly common patterns.

First, the method might take a `B` instance as a parameter. For example:

```
class A:
    def meth(self, b):
        b.meth1()

class B:
    def meth1(self):
        pass

a = A()
b = B()
a.meth(b)
```

To make this more concrete, imagine that `A` is a `Car`, and `B` is a `TollRoad`, and `my_car.drive(my_road)` has to call `my_road.pay_toll()`.

---

Alternatively, each `A` instance may own a `B` instance as a member. For example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
    def meth(self):
        self.b.meth1()

class B:
    def meth1(self):
        pass

b = B()   
a = A(b)
a.meth()
```

To make this more concrete, imagine that `A` is a `Car` again, and `B` is a ServiceCenter, and `my_car.schedule_service()` needs to call `my_car.service_center.get_next_appointment()`.

---

As a variation to the latter, each `B` instance may be a sort of part-of-the-whole of an `A` instance, constructed automatically by the `A` instance. For example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B()
    def meth(self):
        self.b.meth1()

class B:
    def meth1(self):
        pass

a = A()
a.meth()
```

For this one, imagine that `A` is a `Car` again, and `B` is an `Engine`. So, `my_car.drive()` starts off calling `my_car.engine.start()`. But, unlike a `ServiceCenter`, which is a thing that lives on its own and is used by many cars, an `Engine` is only used by the car it's part of, so there's no good reason to create the engine separately and pass it to the car (unless you're modeling a car factory).

Answer (score 1):

B is being used as a static class.

```
class A:
    def meth(self):
        B.meth1()

class B:
    @staticmethod
    def meth1():
        pass

a = A()
a.meth()
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this got upvoted, since there are two earlier answers that say the exact same thing, with more explanation. But, as with those two, this is probably not what the OP wants—or, if it is, he probably shouldn't want it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A:
    def meth(self):
        "create instance of B class"
        b = B()
        b.meth1()
```

Also you can declare B.meth1() as static:

```
class B:
    @staticmethod
    def meth1():
        pass
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
class A:
    def meth(self):
        "create instance of B class"
        B.meth1()
```

Comment: This does get rid of the error, but it's probably not what the OP actually wants to do.

Comment: Check my update. I've mentioned the static approach as well now

Comment: And that's even _less_ likely to be what he wants. There are not many good uses for `@staticmethod`s. (Of course there are _some_—but it's uncommon enough that if a novice thinks he wants a `staticmethod` he probably wants to rethink his design.)

Answer (score 0):

Here B.meth1 is an *instance method*, and you are attempting to use it as a *class method*. You can either re-define B.meth1 to be a classmethod:

```
class B:
  @classmethod
  def meth1(cls):
    pass
```

Or, you can call it as an instance method by instantiating the B class:

```
class A:
    def meth(self):
        B().meth1()
```

Comment: This is pretty much the same as hek2mgl's answer, and it has the same problems: It will get rid of the error, but it probably won't do what the OP is hoping to do (unless he's got an unusual use case, or a bad design).